# Consumer group has no active members - Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

What is the meaning of the message "Consumer group has no active members" when one tries to describe a kafka-consumer-group?

In-depth explanation appreciated.

Comment: In my case, accompanied by an ERROR logged by `org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams`: `All stream threads have died. The instance will be in error state and should be closed.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Managing Consumer Groups](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_consumer_group) Yes, `members` command will only show the consumers that are active in group

```
> bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --group my-group --members
```

> --members: This option provides the list of all active members in the consumer group

**What is a Consumer ?**

Consumer is a thread that subscribe to one or more topics and process the stream of records

**What is Consumer group ?**

Kafka uses the concept of consumer groups to allow a pool of processes to divide the work of consuming and processing records. These processes can either be running on the same machine or they can be distributed over many machines to provide scalability and fault tolerance for processing. All consumer instances sharing the same group.id will be part of the same consumer group.

**Consumer group has no active members**

If consumer threads of specific group are actively polling data from kafka topic are said to be active. If none of consumer threads are active then that group has no active consumers

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the consumer-group might work but still, when describing the consumer-group you might have "no active members". The reason can be found in here:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-3067

Comment: That a specific example, I wouldn't say it is a "valid" consumer group in the kafka meaning, as explained in the answer : Basically we are letting the spout manage which processes consume which partitions, rather than letting Kafka control it, and that's why you're seeing a different output. When it's referring to "active members" it means KafkaConsumers that are currently letting Kafka control their subscriptions. Since the spout controls the subscription manually, its consumer isn't considered an active member.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround I found is if you can somehow keep your consumer app running (using say while(true) ro something like that) it works.

```
while (true) {
  ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(
    Duration.ofMillis(500)
  );

  for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
    logger.info("Key : " + record.key() + " value : " + record.value());
    logger.info(
      "Partition : " + record.partition() + " offset : " + record.offset()
    );
    logger.info("Topic : " + record.topic());
  }
  // break;
}
```

and then if I run the command in terminal :
./bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --group my_first_con_1

I get this o/p :

GROUP           TOPIC           PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID                                                    HOST            CLIENT-ID
my_first_con_1  my-first-topic  0          9               9               0               consumer-my_first_con_1-1-4dbc5583-e560-4234-81a7-9bd9c9803374 /192.168.1.5    consumer-my_first_con_1-1
my_first_con_1  my-first-topic  1          6               6               0               consumer-my_first_con_1-1-4dbc5583-e560-4234-81a7-9bd9c9803374 /192.168.1.5    consumer-my_first_con_1-1
my_first_con_1  my-first-topic  2          15              15              0               consumer-my_first_con_1-1-4dbc5583-e560-4234-81a7-9bd9c9803374 /192.168.1.5    consumer-my_first_con_1-1

Answer (score 0):

The consumer detail may not be present if

a. the consumer was never live

b. the ttl for __consumer_offset is less than the last active time for consumer group.

c. the replication factor for __consumer_offset is 1 and there was data loss for the particular partition.